# How to write a dictionary to a text file with columns for each element in the dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, file-writing

I am trying to use a previously generated Workspace from matlab to create a input text file for another program to read from. I can import the Workspace into Python with no issues as a dictionary. From here I am having difficulty writing to a text file due to the different data types and different sized arrays in the dictionary. I would like for each field in the dictionary to have its own column in the text file but have had little luck.
Here is a screen shot of the imported dictionary from matlab.
[image]

I would like the text file to have this format. (the header is not necessary)
[image]

I was able to get one of the variables into the text file with the following code but, I can't add more variables or ones with different data types.

```py
import csv
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
#import json
#import _pickle as pickle
#import pandas as pd

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('Day055.mat')
#print(type(mat))
#print(mat['CC1'])
CC1 = mat['CC1']
CC2 = mat['CC2']
DP1 = mat['DP1']
#print(CC1)
#print(CC2)

dat = np.array([CC1, DP1])
dat =dat.T

#np.savetxt('tester.txt', dat, delimiter = '\t')
np.savetxt('tester.txt', CC1, delimiter = '\t')

'''
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in CC1:
        writer.writerow(row)
#print(type(CC1))

#print("CC1=", CC1)
#print("first entry to CC1:", CC1[0])
mat = {'mat':mat}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mat)
print(df)

print(type(mat))

x=0

with open('inputDay055.txt', 'w') as file:
    for line in CC1:
        file.write(CC1[x])
        #file.write("\t".join(map(str, CC2))+"\n")
    #file.write(pickle.dumps(mat))
        x=x+1
'''

print("all done")
```

As you can see I have tried a few different ways as well but commented them out when I was not succesful.

Comment: Can you please fix your code formatting in the post? It seems like most parts of it are commented out.

Comment: Can you please provide some data from the `Day055.mat` file, so everybody can reproduce with copy and paste?